# AppSheetのAutomationで、BehaviorタブのActionsを実行する方法を教えてください。

Tags: google-apps-script

#### 問題の要約

AppSheetでDataをCSVを定期的に出力したいと考えています。
アプリ上のボタンを押して、CSVを出力させることはBehaviorタブのActionsからできました。
しかし、Automationを用いてActionsを実行することができませんでした。

#### これまでに試したこと

- 公式ドキュメントの読み込み
- AutomationタブのTasksからCSV出力の実行を試みる（Dataの設定が悪いらしく失敗）

お手数をおかけしますが、Automationで、Actionsを実行する方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

#### 回答を基に行ったこと（追記）

代替手段の案を基に、PDF作成を行ってみました。
とと-to10さんのおかげで、
実際にAutomationを用いてPDFが出力されるまでを行うことができました。
本当にありがとうございます。このままCSVも作成してみます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Automationを用いてActionsを実行することができませんでした。

実行できるのはDataタイプ(※)のアクションだけだったと思うので、Appタイプは実行できないのではないかと思います。
※ActionsのDo Thisで選択できる各項目のセミコロン(:)の左にある文字列（Data,App,Externalなど）をタイプと呼んでいます。

やりたいことは、定期的に実行してCSVをGoogleドライブに格納するなりメールで送るようなイメージかと思いました。代替手段の案を考えました。
データ構造がわからないと思うのでどこまで伝わるかわかりませんがこの方法でCSV出力できました。
ご参考まで。

#### やること

指定したスケジュールで、GoogleドライブにCSVを出力

#### Bot設定概要

Events :  「Schedule」を使う
　Tasks: 「Create a new file」を使う

#### Events設定

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### Tasks設定

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

●上記画像の「Template」で指定するテンプレートの中身

```
"見積書ID","商品ID","個数","小計"
<<Start: SELECT(見積明細[_ComputedKey],TRUE)>>"<<[見積書ID]>>","<<[商品ID]>>","<<[個数]>>","<<[小計]>>"
<<End>>
```

テンプレートの書き方は以下のページが参考になると思います。

[Using CSV templates | AppSheet Help Center](https://help.appsheet.com/en/articles/5297633-using-csv-templates#:%7E:text=on%20Google%20Drive.-,Manually%20creating%20a%20CSV%20template,-Manually%20create%20a)

#### 私の検証で得られた結果（CSVをUPできなかったので画像で）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

●GoogleドライブにCSVが溜まっていく様子
※画像の最終更新時間は気にしないでください。「修正->Botスケジュール設定->検証」を繰り返したため時間はバラバラです。動作確認できたのでちゃんとBotスケジュール設定すれば定期実行できると思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。
まさか、Dataタイプのアクションのみが実行可能とは思いませんでした。

公式サイトでの記載も見つけました。ありがとうございます。
https://help.appsheet.com/en/articles/4865332-step-the-essentials#h_da78adaf87

Comment: その後解決したか気になっていたのでご連絡ありがとうございます。5万円の請求書が私宛なっててびっくりしました(笑) が、解決されたようで良かったです！